# Entering polytonic Greek in emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, fonts, internationalization, multilingual

I am having precisely the problem reported by [this](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-for-windows/issues/detail?id=3) guy.  I have installed the latest version of emacs on my Windows computer, and I find that pasting Greek text into an emacs buffer works fine so long as I change the font from the default but that typing in Greek does not work.  I did some web searching about the problem, and it seems there may be some old-fashioned workarounds, but I I don't understand why entering Greek using the standard Windows polytonic Greek keyboard doesn't just work, as it does in all (most?) other Windows programs.

By the way, another issue I have noticed is that there seems to be quite a restricted number of fonts that have polytonic Greek glyphs.  (And I haven't found any fixed width ones at all!)  Is there any way to make emacs always display the correct characters, even if it has to borrow the glyphs from another font?  Surely the ugliness of something being in the wrong font is better than the brokenness of it not showing up at all.

Comment: I have no idea how to make Emacs work with the Windows keyboard, but you can use input methods to enter polytonic Greek.  Type ``C-u \`` to select an input method, and `C-h I` to see a description.  `greek-babel`, `greek-ibycus4` and `greek-mizuochi` seem to have polytonic letters.  (About borrowing glyphs from another font - I'd like to have that feature as well!)

Comment: That said, if you type `C-h c` and then an "untypable" character, what do you see in the echo area?

Comment: Trying to test that made me realize another major problem with just using the standard Windows keyboard to enter Greek in emacs: it's not even possible to run any commands without switching back to the latin keyboard.  I guess that makes using these "input methods" unavoidable.  It appears that all of the predefined ones are different from the Windows one (which is based on the modern Greek keyboard), but I will have to investigate more carefully.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For the keyboard problem, you might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug` since it sounds like something we should fix (but I can't fix it myself).  For the fonts, this part has seen regular improvements with every new Emacs release, so if you're running Emacs-23, you might want to try again with Emacs-24, and if it's still not showing you those glyphs, please `M-x report-emacs-bug` as well.